# Finding the number of trials

Tags: distributions

If the probability of success is 0.09, how many trials are required to have a probability of at least one success as 1/3 or more?

Comment: Since this question is rather vague, the correct answer is: You need at least three trials to achieve one success out of three trials.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the probability of failure is 0.91; and the probability of n out of n failures if $0.91^n$.The probability of at least one success for n trials is thus $1-0.91^n$.  If we solve for $0.3=1-0.91^n$ what do we get? (I'm not finishing this for you in case it is homework).